# How to import CSV into Sqlite in R where one of the variables has a comma (,) within quotes?

Tags: r, sqlite, csv

This is driving me mad.

I have a csv file "hello.csv"

```
a,b
"drivingme,mad",1
```

I just want to convert this into a sqlite database from within R (I need to do this because the actual file is actually 10G and it won't fit into a data.frame, so I will use Sqlite as an intermediate datastore)

```
dbWriteTable(conn= dbConnect(SQLite(), 
            dbname="c:/temp/data.sqlite3", 
             name="data", 
             value="c:/temp/hello.csv",row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

The above code failed with error

```
Error in try({ : 
  RS-DBI driver: (RS_sqlite_import: c:/temp/hello.csv line 2 expected 2 columns of data but found 3)
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(fn, sep = sep, header = header, skip = skip, nrows = nrows,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'c:/temp/hello.csv'
```

How do I tell it to treat comma (,) within a quote "" is to be treat as string and not a separator!

I tried adding in the argument

```
quote="\""
```

But it didn't work. Help!! read.csv work just file it will fail when reading large files.

Comment: It is a [known limitation](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).
A quick workaround, if you control the way the file was generated, would be to change the separator, say to `|` or `\t`, provided this character does not appear anywhere else in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

A much better now is to use `readr`'s chunked functions e.g.

```r
#setting up sqlite
con_data = dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="yoursqlitefile")

readr::read_delim_chunked(file, function(chunk) {
  dbWriteTable(con_data, chunk, name="data", append=TRUE )) #write to sqlite 
})
```

## Original more cumbuersome way

One way to do this is to read from the file since read.csv works but it just cannot load the whole data into memory.

```
    n = 100000 # experiment with this number
    f = file(csv) 
    con = open(f) # open a connection to the file
    data <-read.csv(f,nrows=n,header=TRUE)
    var.names = names(data)    
 
    #setting up sqlite
    con_data = dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="yoursqlitefile")
  
    while(nrow(data) == n) { # if not reached the end of line
      dbWriteTable(con_data, data, name="data",append=TRUE )) #write to sqlite 
      data <-read.csv(f,nrows=n,header=FALSE))
      names(data) <- var.names      
    } 
    close(f)
    if (nrow(data) != 0 ) {      
      dbWriteTable(con_data, data, name="data",append=TRUE ))
```

Comment: I had the same question as the OP and this answer worked for me. Even though I see it work, however, I cannot figure out how the code increments by 100000 rows each iteration. Could you please explain?

Comment: The every time this line happens `read.csv(f,nrows=n,header=FALSE)`, another `n` lines are read from file `f`. By opening a connection to the file, the "read to up which line" is kept, so it just keeps on reading.

Answer (score 0):

Improving the proposed answer:

```
data_full_path <- paste0(data_folder, data_file)
con_data <- dbConnect(SQLite(),
  dbname=":memory:") # you can also store in a .sqlite file if you prefer

readr::read_delim_chunked(file =  data_full_path,
                          callback =function(chunk,
                                             dummyVar # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826461/9071968
                                             ) {
                            dbWriteTable(con_data, chunk, name="data", append=TRUE ) #write to sqlite 
                            },
  delim = ";",
  quote = "\""
)
```

(The other, current answer with readr does not work: parentheses are not balanced, the chunk function requires two parameters, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826461/9071968)

Answer (score -1):

You make a parser to parse it.

```
string = yourline[i];
if (string.equals(",")) string = "%40";
yourline[i] = string;
```

or something of that nature.  You could also use:

```
string.split(",");
```

and rebuild your string that way.  That's how I would do it.

Keep in mind that you'll have to "de-parse" it when you want to get the values back.  Commas in SQL mean column, so it can really screw things up, not to mention JSONArrays or JSONObjects.

Also keep in mind that this might be very costly for 10GB of data, so you might want to start by parsing the input before it even gets to the CSV if possible..