# Error: `callback` must have two or more arguments - readr

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to create sqlite database via R. (it does not seem very handy, but it should work.)

I am using readr and dplyr package. As I have huge dataset, I am trying to split the datasets via read_delim_chunked, and calling callback function I wrote :

```
modifier<-function(chunk){
  result<-cbind(chunk %>% 
        filter(X1=="T") %>% 
        select(X2) %>% transmute(date=parse_date_time2(X2, orders = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
      chunk %>% 
        filter(X1=="U") %>% 
        select(X2) %>% transmute(str_sub(X2, 20)), 
      chunk %>% 
        filter(X1=="W")%>% 
        select(X2))
  names(result)<-c("time", "user", "tweet")
  db_insert_into(con=my_db$con, table="my_fav_table", values=result)
}
```

However,when calling  read_delim_chunked:

```
read_delim_chunked(file="/datadrive/tweets2009-07.txt", 
                   chunk_size = 99999, 
                   callback = modifier, 
                   delim = "\t", 
                   escape_double = FALSE, 
                   col_names = FALSE, 
                   trim_ws = TRUE, 
                   skip = 1)
```

I am getting this weird error:

> Error: `callback` must have two or more arguments

What is passed onto the second argument, that it needs to be there?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding a second argument and seeing what gets passed, and try running with the debugger. There are some possible hints here ?DataFrameCallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks default to a class called SideEffectChunkCallback. This class contains a function called receive that gets called everytime a chunk is read in. This is the function definition [(Git)](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/f5c653b3aab115a7e10122b763b41c0713de7006/R/callback.R#L72):

```
receive = function(data, index) {
  result <- private$callback(data, index)
  private$cancel <- identical(result, FALSE)
}
```

It gets called like this [(Git)](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/f5c653b3aab115a7e10122b763b41c0713de7006/src/read.cpp#L132)

```
 R6method(callback, "receive")(out, pos);
```

where out is the current data frame chunk and pos is the line number in the file where the current chunk begins. I'm not sure why they pass the index back (it isn't used) and force your callback function to have a parameter for it. I just added a dummy variable to my callback function like this which works fine.

```
myCallBackFunction <- function(dfChunk, dummyVar){
```